# Spikes in execution time for cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a pretty dead simple cloud function that writes a single value to my real-time database. The code is at the bottom of this post.

Watching the logs, I'm finding that the execution time is highly inconsistent. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

You can see that it's as low as 3ms (great!) and *as high as 579ms* (very bad-- and I've seen it reach 1000ms). The result is very noticeable delays in my chatroom implementation, with messages sometimes being appended out of order from how they were sent. (i.e. "1" "2" "3" is being received as "2" "3" "1")

Why might execution time vary this wildly? Cold start vs warm start doesn't seem to apply since you can see these calls happened directly one after the other. I also can't find any documented limits on writes/sec for real-time db, unlike the 1 write/sec limit on firestore documents.

Here's the code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

const messagesRef = admin.database().ref('/messages/general');

export const sendMessageToChannel = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      'failed-precondition', 
      'User must be logged-in.'
    );
  }

  try {
    await messagesRef.push({
      uid: context.auth.uid,
      displayName: data.displayName,
      body: data.body
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('aborted', error);
  }
});
```

**Edit:** I've seen [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51759752/firebase-cloud-functions-execution-time-is-so-fluctuate) from two years ago, where the responder indicates that the tasks themselves have variable execution time.

Is that the case here? Does the real-time database have wildly variable write times (varying by ~330x, from 3ms to 1000ms!)?

Comment: What are the message ID? Can you show an example of data stored in your database?

Comment: Since Firebase Functions share the same infrastructure as Google Cloud Functions, have you tried any of these [tips and best pratices](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#performance)? They may help you with performance issues. Please also take a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#scalability) to find out more about scalability. From the logs I noticed that your Function execution took 3 ms and the response status was _204_, which means that no content was found. Is this the function log you meant? Does this help you at all?

Comment: When I change the function to return a literal value with no reads or writes to firestore, execution time drops to ~5ms. It seems it really is the time it takes to read/write a single simple value to the database. I just don't understand why the things I read/write from the client/code are instantaneous, but doing it through a cloud function (for more sensitive operations) has this delay.

Comment: have you tried specifying your [cloud functions locations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations)? If your cloud functions are located close to your database, you will minimize the latency

Comment: The documentation on this is fairly sparse alright. I can only assume that where your previous execution of the function ran - that perhaps the environment no longer has any capacity. I haven't used Cloudfunctions - but am more familiar with AWS Lambda - and even though your function may be warm - its execution context can still be moved after n number of invocations - giving a cold start (albeit a shorter ramp up time). I guess that was the motivation for provisioned concurrency in Lambda - hopefully GCP will introduce something similar.

Comment: @silopus I think you just answered the question. 3ms for the no-content status-only res... Sure it isnt enough info for us to solve affirmatively, but OP is a different story. Ill bet you 100 rep that if you were to C/V your comment to an answer, you would get the rep... I am guessing that that status code is enough info for op to answer his/ her own question. Or maybe not. 2 & 3 still have quite the gap between.

Comment: One of the requests has a 204 response code. Could have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

That's something quite hard to control based on the code. 
You have a lot of steps going on there: \

1. verifying the user authentication
2. send his message to the collection
3. trying to catch any possible errors

So you can't rely simply on response time to organize the messaging order. 
You should be setting a serverside timestamp from within the client side to trace that.

You can achieve this with the following explained piece of code:

```
try {
    message.createdAt = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() // server-side timestamp
    ... // calls to functions
} catch(err) {
    console.log("Couldn't set timestamp or send to functions")
}
```

This way you would set a server side timestamp for your message before sending it to be saved, so your users would see whenever a message is being registered (timestamp), saved (functions call) and confirmed (200 when sent).